# VS Code Git Controls in Explorer view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

Does somebody know why my git controls are suddenly part of the normal folder view in VS Code? Is this a new VS Code Update. Because it is absolutely attrocious to use. This is a simple example, if you have a bigger codebase, or open multiple repositories in on VS Code Window, it is completely unusable.

I'm on 1.66.2.

[image]

Comment: what if you execute command: **Reset View Locations**

Comment: @rioV8 Yes, that fixes the layout back to default.